MongoDb error when deploying app on Cpanel: session: options?.session - Unexpected token
I am trying to deploy my app in Cpanel, and I keep getting the following error:
/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/admin.js:62
session: options?.session,
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
I have the latest version of Node. My app is also on Render and I didn't have any problems there..only in Cpanel.
I updated Node to the latest versions, restarted everything and it still doesn't work.
